# Regular Expression to remove a single leading "1", with more regular expression after removing the one

Tags: regex

I'm a regex beginner here.  I have a regular expression to check for license plate text:

```
[A-Z0-9]{6,8}
```

This accepts any strings that have 6, 7, or 8 characters that are letters capital A-Z or digits 0-9.

I'd like to add something at the beginning to throw out a single leading `1`.  For example:

original `1ABC123`
new `ABC123` (remove the leading "1")

original `111ABCDE`
new `11ABCDE` (only remove a single "1")

original `ABC1234`
new `ABC1234` (no change)

original `9876543`
new `9876543` (no change)

Please keep in mind I have to retain the `[A-Z0-9]{6,8}` part after removing the leading 1, if present.

I'm using `boost::regex_match` in C++ to actually process the regex if that matters.

As a quick aside, the site I'm using to check this is https://regex101.com/ which is a bit awkward, does anybody have an alternative suggestions for a regex checking site?

Comment: I think you need to use `boost::regex_replace` for this, with `^1(.*?[A-Z0-9]{6,8})` or `^1([A-Z0-9]{6,8})` pattern to search and `$1` as the replacement pattern. See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/AqaLb7/1).

Comment: "^1{1}" should find a single leading 1.  Or also "^1?" May suit your needs

Comment: Also, why is regex101 "awkward"? It is the best regex checking site I have ever come across.

Comment: Still working on it at the moment.  I appreciate all the good suggestions.  I'll accept the answer when things are complete.

Comment: Please clarify what you are doing, else there is no point in accepting any answers as they might fail to actually help you, especially when you do not provide feedback.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the optional match character `?` to check for the 1 at the beginning of the regex:

```
1?[A-Z][0-9]{6,8}
```

Although, now this allows the license plates to be up to 9 characters long. If that is ok, you can then throw the optional 1 into a non-capturing group to discard it from the resulting matched groups by using the pattern `(?:blah)`:

```
(?:1?)[A-Z0-9]{6,8}
```

If you cannot have up to 9 characters in the plate number, then just have two regexes, one with the optional 1 and one without. Use the pipe character `|` as a logical "or" to match either expression:

```
1[A-Z0-9]{5,7}|[A-Z0-9]{6,8}
```

And again, if you need to ignore the 1 in the output, put it in a non-capturing group:

```
(?:1)[A-Z0-9]{5,7}|[A-Z0-9]{6,8}
```